# How to pass a specific property into a javascript object in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters

I've inherited an old codebase that no one at my company has worked with. There's a jquery plugin being used, with minimal documentation. Here's the part I need:

```
/**
 * @param {String} message      This is the message string to be shown in the popup
 * @param {Object} settings     This is an object containing all other settings for the errorPopup
 * @param {boolean}   settings.close   Optional callback for the Okay button 
 * @returns a reference to the popup object created for manual manipulation
 */
Popup.errorPopup = function(message , settings ){

    settings = settings || {};

    var defaults = {
                    allowDuplicate: false,
                    centerText: true,
                    closeSelector: ".ConfirmDialogClose"
                   }

    settings = $.extend( defaults , settings );

    return Popup.popupFactory(  message,
                                settings,
                                ".ConfirmDialogBox",
                                ".PopupContent"
                             );

}
```

Our current calls to this function just use the default settings; none of them pass anything in. Example:

```
 Popup.errorPopup('Sorry, your account couldn\'t be found.');
```

For one use of this, I need to pass in a callback function for when the popup closes. According to the comments, there is a `settings.close` parameter, but I have no idea how to go about passing it in via the function call.

I tried this:

```
Popup.errorPopup('Sorry, your account couldn\'t be found.', {close: 'streamlinePassword'});
```

where `streamlinePassword` is the name of the callback function.

But got a javascript error: Property 'close' of object # is not a function.

How can I pass this new object param into the function call?

Comment: Have you tried using `{close: streamlinePassword}`, without quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass a string, pass a function.

Samples:

```
function streamlinePassword() {
 // ...
}

Popup.errorPopup('...', {close: streamlinePassword});

// also possible
Popup.errorPopup('...', {
  close: function () {
  }
});

// also possible II
Popup.errorPopup('...', {
  close: function test() {
  }
});
```